# Realm objects (RLMObject) in a single file or multiple files

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, realm

I used `CoreData` in my project for a long time. Now I want to convert it to `Realm`.

In `CoreData` we have defined each entity in separate file groups (a subclass of `NSManagedObject`).

[image]

Now what is the best practice for `Realm` structure? Shall I use different files for defining entities or just put all of them in a single `.m` file as there is an evidence in official example.

[image]

Comment: You should separate the files, the put-all-together examples you're seeing are because the examples should be readed on a website and there's no big space for doing so (and because of brevity.) So yes, create separate classes for every RLMObject subclass.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments it's better to define each class (subclass of `RLMObject`) in a separate `.h+.m` files, it will just help you to keep things separately. However there is no such requirement, so you can put everything to one file, but most likely you don't want to.